# Why am I getting: database is locked, in an SQLite3 script?

Tags: sqlite

I'm getting an error when running an SQLite script.

```
--drop use table before replacing it
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.use;

--Create the use table in the saved database
CREATE TABLE db.use AS SELECT * FROM use2; -- this is the line that generates the error: Error: near line 145: database is locked
```

Are these two statements run asynchronously or something? I don't understand what's causing the error, but I'm wondering if it has to do with that.

Might there be a way to run the script in a lock-step manner, i.e. non-asynchronously?

Comment: Are you certain that there aren't any other threads or other programs accessing the same database at the same time?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: This is the command I'm using to run the script, maybe that has something to do with it: `sqlite3 --init create_db.sql thedb.db`. The script also has an ATTACH statement that reads `thedb.db`, could this be causing a conflict?

Comment: So I ended up running `sqlite3` and then in the prompt entering `.read <script>` and now the errors aren't appearing, so I think it had something to do with the way I was running the script.

Comment: Edit the question to show all the commands you executed. It appears you tried to open the same file twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was running the command: `sqlite3 --init script_name.sql dbname.db`, and elsewhere in the script I had an `ATTACH` statement reading the same database `dbname.db`. Essentially reading the same file twice.

The way I solved this was by executing the script in the sqlite3 shell:

`sqlite3> .read script_name.sql`

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to add a commit statement after the drop statement?
I think that would make sure the create table statement run after the drop statement is totally done.

Comment: I have not. Is it just as simple as: `COMMIT;`?

Comment: Yes, I think so.